# Why Object.assign(...) is working in IE 11?

Tags: javascript

The official documentation mentions that "Object.assign()" is not supported in IE browser. However, I am able to use this function and it works as expected, without any exceptions. Is anyone facing the similar "issue"? Following are my IE settings:

Version: 11.678.17763.0
Update Versions: 11.0.140

Comment: it's your lucky day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed `Object.assign()` is not supported in IE so if you observe this behavior this is probably because you have imported a polyfill.

Comment: Thanks! That was the "issue"